# Change input text to submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm sure it's quite simple. I have a submit form that has a delete confirmation modal. If confirmed it will post data. For design purposes I want the text input that opens the modal to be changed to a button. It works as text input but not a button.

```
<form name="checkbox" id="checkbox" method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="20">
```

Submit button currently:

```
 <input type="text" name="deleteall" value="yes" id="deleteall" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit"/>
```

Want it changed to this, but modal does not come on

```
<button type="submit" value="yes" name="deleteall" id="deleteall" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete</button>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Confirm Submit
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to delete all selected?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                 <button type="submit" id="submit" name="deleteall" value="yes" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#checkbox').submit();
});
```

Comment: `<input type="text">`? Don't you mean `<input type="submit">`?

Comment: It only works as input type=text